# Print file on a local printer using pure Dart with pop up printer window?

Tags: flutter, dart, printing, flutter-desktop

i want to print file which contain in $file variable on a local printer. I want a pop up window just like Java Script window.print(). My question is that how i can do the same job using Dart language only? Actually i am using flutter for windows app and there is plugin available for printing in flutter desktop so i want to use pure dart to print local file.

Comment: some printers have websocket interface which can allow to connect to them and call print. so if You want to print custom file, think about it. https://github.com/vshjxyz/nwjs-print-server

Answer (score 1):

`window.print` just prints out the current web page.

if you want to print a custom $file than first try to load that file in separate browser tab / window. if you are unable to load that file in browser than the only solution left is to natively connect to the operating system and print file from there.

as flutter for windows says that the native plugins should be written in golang

Answer (score 0):

By using a plugin like the one, well, called `printing`. This involves the platform beneath, so it will *not* be pure Dart, though.